# What are the correct terms regarding (this literary) technique?

Tags: terminology

An example comes from a cartoon where there is a woman talking to her boyfriend.

There's a "cloud" that comes from her mouth, and the text inside reads: "You're so handsome." But there is another cloud that comes from the top of her head (brain), and the text reads: "Man, does he have bad breath."

What are these "clouds" called? Would "halo" be a suitable term?

And what is this technique called that shows what a character is really thinking as opposed to what she is saying?

Answer (score 4):

They're called **speech bubbles** and **thought bubbles,** respectively. Speech bubbles usually have clean edges and a kind of triangle pointing to the speaker's mouth; thought bubbles have puffy, cloud-like edges, and the connection to the speaker is a trail of individual round bubbles.

I might call the technique "disconnect," but I'm not sure if that's the official term.

Comment: The thoughts are sometimes called the "internal monologue."

Comment: @ChrisSunami: Very good point. That's the other term I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @TomAu "Internal monologue" is the correct term for the mental stream of consciousness. It may be the same as what the person is saying or it may not; that term doesn't have anything to do with the content.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the "thought bubbles" contain the internal monologue, and the "speech bubbles" the dialog.

Comment: @TomAu Yes. I just wanted to clarify that simply because there are thought bubbles and speech bubbles, it does not require that the content be different.